# Google Maps - Locations and Circle

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I am trying to combine both multiple locations and a circle within the same map, I have had a look around to see how to combine two different element types but I have yet to find anything useful.

Below is some example code that draws a circle:

```
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

var Hotspot=new google.maps.LatLng( 29.9597675231189 , -93.9675262286223 );


function initialize()


{
var mapProp = {
  center:Hotspot,
  zoom:7,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var Circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:Hotspot,
  radius:25000,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#0000FF",
  fillOpacity:0
  });

Circle.setMap(map);


}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now for example if I wishied to place 2 markers at:

lat  29.937641 long -93.969326
lat  30.063964 long -94.116131

How would I incorporate that into the above code? Or visa versa if I had code with points how would I incorporate the circle elements?

As always thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({map:map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.937641,-93.969326)}); var marker2=new google.maps.Marker({map:map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.063964 .-94.116131)});`

Comment: Ah its the simple! Thanks so much for taking the time out to get back to me on this! Have a nice weekend geocodezip!

Answer (score 2):

```
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:Hotspot,
  zoom:7,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({map:map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.937641,-93.969326)}); 
var marker2=new google.maps.Marker({map:map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.063964 .-94.116131)});

var Circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:Hotspot,
  radius:25000,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#0000FF",
  fillOpacity:0
  });

Circle.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: is it best to put the marker elements before or after the circle element or does it not matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter, they both can't be added to the map until after that is initialized.